# How can I get the query string value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am trying to get the query string passed in url using the jquery and pass on it to php function

I have id=61 in url as a query string,I want to get the id value using the   jquery.

How can I do this?

```
review.php?id=61
```

this is my code

```
$('#approve').click(function(){
    var id = "product Approved";      //here i want to get the id value
    alert(id);
    jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update.php",
       data: 'id='+id,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
       }
});
```

Comment: There are loads of duplicates of this question already...

Comment: `type: "POST"` change to `type: "GET"` to pass value into `php` function like: `review.php?id=61`